# How to download a file with Vaadin 10?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin10, vaadin-flow

I want to let user to download a file from server.
I [looked up](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17081792) for the solution and when trying to make an example - ended up with this:

```
@Route("test-download")
public class Download extends VerticalLayout {

    public Download() {
        Anchor downloadLink = new Anchor(createResource(), "Download");
        downloadLink.getElement().setAttribute("download", true);
        add(downloadLink);
    }

    private AbstractStreamResource createResource() {
        return new StreamResource("/home/johny/my/important-file.log", this::createExportr);
    }

    private InputStream createExportr(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Which is giving `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource file name parameter contains '/'` when I go to the page in browser. 
How do I make a download button (or anchor) knowing file location on disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/advanced/tutorial-dynamic-content.html), paragraph "Using StreamResource". The first parameter is just a file name that will be used by the browser to propose that file name to the user when downloading. So you could pass it like `"important-file.log"`. The content of the download is provided by the `InputStream` parameter. For instance, you could read from your file, see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/convert-file-to-input-stream):

```
File initialFile = new File("src/main/resources/sample.txt");
InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(initialFile);
```