# Vaadin Flow download code works for Chrome but not for Firefox - How can I support both?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin10

I have the following code to download a file from Vaadin Flow (12.0.7).

```java
exportBtn.addClickListener(e -> {
toDownload = FileUtil.getLatestExport();

(toDownload != null) {
                StreamResource resource = new StreamResource(toDownload.getName(),
                        () -> FileUtil.getInputStreamForFile(toDownload));

                Element object = new Element("object");
                object.setAttribute("download", true);
                object.setAttribute("data", resource);

                Input name = new Input();
                UI.getCurrent().getElement().appendChild(name.getElement(), object);
   }
});
```

toDownload locates the file which I want to download. If I click the button from Chrome the browser downloads my file if I click the button from Firefox nothing happens. In what way do I need to adjust my code to support Chrome and Firefox?

I used this [tutorial](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17010389/vaadin-10-let-user-download-a-file) as reference.

Comment: Did you try download using the Anchor element as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52150056?

Comment: @SteffenHarbich is correct. The Anchor class should be used to achieve this: https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17081792/is-there-an-equivalent-of-filedownloader-in-v10

Comment: The resource you provided is applicable for Vaadin 8. I'm not sure if I can use it for Vaadin Flow as well. Furthermore I think using the anchor element is only working for static content? Vaadin 10 documentation suggests the way I did it for serving dynamic generated content. https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/advanced/tutorial-dynamic-content.html

Would I use the anchor.setHref method to serve dynamic content in your case?

Comment: Please read the links one more time, it is for Vaadin Flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a workaround for downloads triggered by some action in Vaadin Flow, e.g. you have a button that conditionally shows a dialog before downloading the file:

```
 Anchor hiddenDownloadLink = new Anchor(createYourStreamResource(), "Workaround");
 hiddenDownloadLink.setId("DownloadLinkWorkaround_" + System.currentTimeMillis());
 hiddenDownloadLink.getElement().setAttribute("style", "display: none");
 // TODO: add the link somehwere in your view
 UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("document.getElementById('" + hiddenDownloadLink.getId().orElseThrow() + "').click();");
```

Tested in FF, Chrome and Edge. The workaround simulates a click on an anchor that triggers the download.